# Is there any way to get text inside anchor tag in Scrapy's Crawlspider?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a crawlspider which crawls given site upto certain dept and download the pdfs on that site. Everything works fine but along with link of pdf, i also need text inside anchor tag.

for eg:

```
<a href='../some/pdf/url/pdfname.pdf'>Project Report</a>
```

consider this anchor tag, in callback i get response object and along with this object i need text inside that tag for eg 'Project Report'.
Is there any way to get this information along with the response object. i have gone through https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html link but it not something that i am looking for.

sample code:

```
class DocumunetPipeline(scrapy.Item):
    document_url = scrapy.Field()
    name = scrapy.Field()  # name of pdf/doc file
    depth = scrapy.Field()

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'pdf'
    start_urls = ['http://www.someurl.com']
    allowed_domains = ['someurl.com']
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(tags="a", deny_extensions=[]),
             callback='parse_document', follow=True),
    )


    def parse_document(self, response):
        content_type = (response.headers
                        .get('Content-Type', None)
                        .decode("utf-8"))
        url = response.url
        if content_type == "application/pdf":
            name = response.headers.get('Content-Disposition', None)
            document = DocumunetPipeline()
            document['document_url'] = url
            document['name'] = name
            document['depth'] = response.meta.get('depth', None)
            yield document
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like it's not documented, but the `meta` attribute does contain the link text. It is updated in [this line](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.6/scrapy/spiders/crawl.py#L53).
A minimal example would be:

```py
from scrapy.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class LinkTextSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'linktext'
    start_urls = ['https://example.org']
    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_document'),
    ]

    def parse_document(self, response):
        return dict(
            url=response.url,
            link_text=response.meta['link_text'],
        )
```

Which produces an output similar to:

```
2019-04-01 12:03:30 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-04-01 12:03:30 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-04-01 12:03:30 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-04-01 12:03:31 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://example.org> (referer: None)
2019-04-01 12:03:32 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.iana.org/domains/reserved> from <GET http://www.iana.org/domains/example>
2019-04-01 12:03:33 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.iana.org/domains/reserved> (referer: None)
2019-04-01 12:03:33 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.iana.org/domains/reserved>
{'url': 'https://www.iana.org/domains/reserved', 'link_text': 'More information...'}
2019-04-01 12:03:33 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to achieve that is not to use crawling rules, and instead user regular crawling, with your own `parse_*` methods to handle all responses.

Then, when you yield a request that has `parse_document` as callback, you can include the link text on the `meta` parameter of your request, and read it from `response.meta` on your `parse_document` method.

```py
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'pdf'
    start_urls = ['http://www.someurl.com']
    allowed_domains = ['someurl.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.css('a'):
            yield response.follow(
                link,
                callback=self.parse_document,
                meta={'link_text': link.xpath('text()').get()}
            )


    def parse_document(self, response):
        # …
        if content_type == "application/pdf":
            # …
            document = DocumunetPipeline()
            # …
            document['link_text'] = response.meta['link_text']
            yield document
```